# How do I set the delegate of a NSURLSession instance variable in Swift?

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

have `NSURLSession` as an instance variable on a class, and thus I need to instantiate it in the class' `init` method.

I want to set the delegate as `self` in the instantiation, but I can't use `self` until I call `super.init()`, and I can't call `super.init()` until I instantiate everything, and I need to set the delegate in the instantiation.

How do I set the delegate to `self`? There doesn't seem to be a separate `setDelegate()` function.

Answer (score 1):

The delegate in `NSURLRequest` is not a read/write variable (you can only request it). You have to set it in the initiation. Here is my solution to the problem:

When declaring the variable in the class, use this code:

```
var session: NSURLSession = NSURLSession()
```

Then, after you call `super.init()`, initiate `session` again with the delegate set to self like this:

```
init() {
    super.init()
    session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.ephemeralSessionConfiguration(), delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
}
```

Hope that helps!

### Update for Swift 3:

As usual Swift 3 has simplified this quite a bit, you can now simply do

```
let session = URLSession(configuration: .ephemeral, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
```

Comment: This code sets a default value to use for super.init(), whose pointer will be assigned to a different instance afterwards. Is this right? Shouldn't it be `NSURLSession!`?